# How can I set up Sitecore Commerce Demo Site (Sitecore.Demo.Retail) to exclude configuration errors?

Tags: sitecore8, sitecore-commerce-server, sitecore-ecommerce

When I set up the **sitecore demo retail** site (source - https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Retail), I encountered with several problems related to **Sitecore Commerce configurations** and **Sitecore Engine Configurations**. I will divide this issues:

1. I got the following error while running the **install-commerce-server.ps1 script on step 5 (Commerce Server Configuration)**
   [image]
2. I got error '**HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure**' by URL - http://habitat.commerceengine.dev.local:5000/api/$metadata
   [image]
3. On 'reatil.dev.local' site I got error 'C**ould not find property 'shopName' on object of type: Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.CommerceEngineConfiguration**', when I tried to go on any page with products
   [image]
4. I encountered with some errors of Sitecore Commerce Applications (**Merchandising Manager**, **Pricing & Promotions**) in Sitecore Experience Platform
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: So what's the question? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I investigated and aggregated this problems in set up processing of Sitecore.Demo.Retail solution.

Comment: If these are the problems you are facing and you already have solution for it then wait for someone to ask these questions. This site is not for blogging.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I know. I think, that there are a lot another reasons of appearing of this issues. I want to see them, and help for developers, which will face with such problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However, I have resolved this issues and I hope that this info will be useful for set up of **Sitecore Demo Retail** site (https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Retail).
I have repeated instuctions for install of **Sitecore.Demo.Retail** and fixed related issues:

1. This issue had discussed in https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Retail/issues/81. You need to check file 'Server2012_FeaturesRequired.txt' like it stated in issued-81. Then you must check file **csconfig.xml** (path for me - 'c:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\install'). I had bad SQL connection to MSSQL Server, which was default. Here example of working variant:
   [image]
   **By another way** you can run Commerce Server Configurator manually by '**CSConfig.exe /f**' (path for me - 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Commerce Server 11\'). Then you can load xml-configuration and set and test SQL connection:
   [image]
2. This issue appeared on my environment, because i had wrong SQL connections (by default) in Commerce Engine project in Sitecore.Demo.Retail solution. You must to change all connections in the following files Global.json, Habitat.CommerceAuthoring-1.0.0.json, Habitat.CommerceShops-1.0.0.json.
   !!!**Don't afraid to check appropriate configs in deployed solution**
   [image]
3. This error is appeared due the wrong tags (**storefront**) in '**commerceEngineConfiguration**' tag. You need to remove this tags in **Sitecore.Demo.Retail.config** file. Working variant for example in showConfig.aspx:
   [image]
4. You should to check connection strings in file **Z.Sitecore.Commerce.UX.Shared.config** (path for me - c:\websites\habitat.dev.local\Website\App_Config\Include). By default I had 'localhost:5000/...'
   [image]